# Size difference between transaction log and deleted rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I recently had to delete a large number of records and forgetting to set the recovery model to Simple the usual happened and the log exploded in size. The thing that puzzled me was why when deleting 10GB of data the log grew to around 35GB? Shouldn't it be just deleting 10GB and having a transaction log of 10GB? What additional info is sql server storing with each record? I couldn't find and answer on the interwebs, so I hope someone here could explain that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The log writes out any pages (of 8kb) changes in a transaction, regardless how much data inthe page changed.

As such, depending how you delete it (i.e. row by row) it may be significantly larger.

Also do not forget that 10g of data mean data. How many additional pages are indices? And yes, iirc those are also stored.